# Calculating probabilities over a population

Tags: c#, probability

The title may not be descriptive of what I'm actually trying to do because I'm not sure exactly what it's called.

I'm trying to calculate the outcome (**using c#**) of a population where each item in the population has a probability of being selected. For example, say there are ten people, and there is a 10% chance that any given person will be selected for an outcome. So for outcome1 maybe 3 people are selected but for outcome2 maybe 0 are selected.

I understand how to calculate the outcome for 1 person given a 10% chance:

```
Random r = new Random();
double v = r.nextDouble();

if (v <= 0.10) { return 1; }
return 0;
```

But how would I do this over a given population?

Comment: Not the downvoter (thinking about it though). This doesn't seem like a programming question yet. Its a math question with some code explaining what you are doing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about calculating a probability which is a math question, not a programming one.

Comment: seems like a code question to me since I'm writing it in c#

Comment: Sure, but *most* math problems can be coded in a given language. First you need to understand the math (a math question), *then* you could ask about how to implement it in code here if you run into trouble with that.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I'm doing? I've run into trouble calculating it over a population

Comment: You just contradicted yourself! You are having trouble **calculating** it. Not *implementing a calculation in code*. If you *know* how to hand-calculate this problem, then you should indicate the normal algorithm and where you are having trouble translating that into code.

Comment: How do you tell a computer to do the same calculation over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a function that takes a population size, and a given probability of an individual event, and delivers a random outcome?

So something like:

```
public int Outcome(int p, int n){
     var random = new Random();
     int count = 0;
     int rnd = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
          rnd = random.Next(0, 100);
          if (rnd <= p) count++;
     }

     return count;
}
```

where `p` is the probability of a single event as a percentage (so 10 in your example) and `n` is the population size (again, 10 in your example.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to extract 10% of a list of `Person` ( the population ), 
given a list of `Person` you can select some of them like this :

```
Random r = new Random();
List< Person > population;
// fill the population list
var selectedPopulation = population.Where( x=> r.nextDouble() < 0.1 ).ToList();
```

You can then iterate the selected person :

```
foreach( var person in selectedPopulation )
{
   // do you work
}
```